# Global scope not printing data

Tags: php, global-variables

Why is $a not printing?

And what is the alternate of this, and I dont want to use return.

```
function abc () {
    $a = 'abc';
    global $a;
}

abc();
echo $a;
```

Comment: Well, to begin with you actually have to *call* the function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `return`?

Comment: Simple, you can't declare it `global` "after" a variable. Global must be declared "before" the variable (not with what you posted for code). Plus, you need to place your `echo $a;` inside your function, then replace what's outside your function with calling the `abc();` function instead. (tested)

Comment: I dont want to put inside i want to echo $a outside of function
@Fred-ii-

Comment: Because of my program needs.
@Arjan

Comment: Sorry my mistake, but i called while testing
@Jon

Comment: The answer on the question is too obvious.

Comment: You still need to put your global statement above `$a = 'abc';` then instead of `echo $a;` use `abc();  echo $a;` @SaadKing

Comment: Tnx @Fred-ii- You Solved My Problem!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. You should have asked me to make it an answer then ;-) @SaadKing

Comment: @SaadKing You may want to reconsider those program needs. When you use `global`s, it's very easy to introduce bugs that are very hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's not echoing is because of two things:

1) You need to declare `global` "before" the variable you wish to define as being global.

and

2) You also need to **call** the function.

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php
function abc()
{
global $a;
$a = 'abc';
}

abc();
echo $a;
```

For more information on variable scopes, visit the PHP.net website:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get your variable as:

```
 echo  $GLOBALS['a'];
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use define():

```
function abc() {
    define("A", "abc");
}
abc();
echo A;
```

Make sure you call the function.  I added that just above echo.

Comment: But you need to realise that `define()` is not the same as a variable. Once defined, you cannot change a const.

Answer (score 0):

First you must create and assign a variable. And then in you function describe that is a global var you want to use.

```
$a = 'zxc';

function abc() {
    global $a;

    $a = 'abc';
} 

abc();
echo $a;
```

This is not really good idea to use golbal such way. I don't really understand why I so much want to use a global var...

But my opinion is better for you to use a pointer to variable.

```
function abc(&$var){
  $var = 'abc';
}

$a = 'zxc';

abc(&$a);
echo $a;
```

Or even would be better to create an object and then access variable with-in this object